# Differet Result from CryptoJS in javascript and Mcrypt in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

The first code is for the jscript (cryptoJS) which actually encrypts a data i provide. I also did the same in mcrypt in php together with the constant IV key and some key provided. It turns out that some results are different. The IV key are different when called as well as the keybase64. Have a look

Here the JSCRIPT(cryptoJS)

```
function crypto_encrypt(text) {                                                                        //This is for JS
var keyBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("ITU2NjNhI0tOc2FmZExOTQ==");
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==');

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(text), keyBase64,
    {
        keySize: 128 / 8,
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

// Returns a Base64 encoded string.
return encrypted;
```

}

Then I called it with this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='./jquery.soap.js'></script>
<!--<script type='text/javascript' src='./soapclient.js'></script>-->

<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='./HCSConnect.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var encryptedname = crypto_encrypt('Patrick'); 
alert(encryptedname);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is `Y44Ktqd/b2VpbdUFaXR8bg==`

Now when I use the mcrypt in php like this

```
<?php
$Pass = "Password";
$Clear = "Patrick";
//$sSecretKey = ("ITU2NjNhI0tOc2FmZExOTQ==");       

$crypted = fnEncrypt($Clear, $Pass);
echo "Encrypred: ".$crypted."</br>";

$newClear = fnDecrypt($crypted, $Pass);
echo "Decrypted: ".$newClear."</br>"; 



function fnEncrypt($sValue, $sSecretKey)
{
return rtrim(
    base64_encode(
        mcrypt_encrypt(
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192,
            ("ITU2NjNhI0tOc2FmZExOTQ=="),$sValue, 
           MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, 
            $iv = ('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==')
            )
      ), "\0"
    );
}

function fnDecrypt($sValue, $sSecretKey)
{
return rtrim(
    mcrypt_decrypt(
        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192, 
        ("ITU2NjNhI0tOc2FmZExOTQ=="), 
        base64_decode($sValue), 
        MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
        $iv = ('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==')
    ), "\0"
);
}
?>
```

The answer is `xjjhImM0ZmS6roSthDAnbUwYB1ihnve1`

where did i went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You don't base64_decode your key and iv:

```
function fnEncrypt($sValue, $sSecretKey)
{
return rtrim(
    base64_encode(
        mcrypt_encrypt(
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192,
            base64_decode("ITU2NjNhI0tOc2FmZExOTQ=="),$sValue, // added base64_decode
           MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, 
            $iv = base64_decode('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==') // added base64_decode
            )
      ), "\0"
    );
}
```

Same the other function.